# Flutter Firebase fliter arrayContainsAny

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of Strings that is filled dynamically(at mas 5 items). Now i want to filter my documents from firsestore based on those items, so i wrote this:

```
List<String> lst= new List();
lst.add('A');
lst.add('B');
lst.add('C');
    Query collectionRef = Firestore.instance
        .collection("files")
        .document(Userpref.language)
        .collection("files")
        .where("describeFear", arrayContainsAny: [
       lst
    ]);
```

Inside the [] if i put the list name it will not work.
Also if i put all the items in the list in a variable and pass it to the [] it will not work .

The only time it works is when I put the values like this 'A','B','C'. This works, but i need to pass the array couse its dynamic .
Can anyone help ?

Comment: What you showed right now won't work, because you're not passing any items into `arrayContainsAny`, but I don't think that's what you're actually stuck at. Can you update the code in your question to show the exact, complete/standalone code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting your `List` object into an array, so you end up looking for documents that have an array where one single item is `["A", "B", "C"]`.

What you want is:

```
List<String> lst= new List();
lst.add('A');
lst.add('B');
lst.add('C');

Query collectionRef = Firestore.instance
    .collection("files")
    .document(Userpref.language)
    .collection("files")
    .where("describeFear", arrayContainsAny: lst);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to be using whereIn instead of arrayContainsAny for this use case

```js
List<String> lst= new List();
lst.add('A');
lst.add('B');
lst.add('C');

Query collectionRef = Firestore.instance
    .collection("files")
    .document(Userpref.language)
    .collection("files")
    .where("describeFear", whereIn: [
   lst
]);
```

Comment: you save my day, bro. Thank you a lot! Have a blessed day :)

Answer (score 2):

With latest version of:
Flutter + cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2

I'm facing a similar issue, the query is returning empty data:

```
          FutureBuilder(
          future: _sessionsLogCollection
              .where('companyId', isEqualTo: sPData.companyId)
              .where('locationId', arrayContainsAny: [
                '29L73oSzdQrzLUow3Mg9',
                'bugdWVC6RRtHoemuxNWE',
              ])
              // .where('locationId', isEqualTo: 'bugdWVC6RRtHoemuxNWE')
              .orderBy('openDateTime', descending: true)
              .get(),
```

I already have indexes created, so that isn't the problem.

When using **.where('locationId', isEqualTo: 'bugdWVC6RRtHoemuxNWE')** alone, the query returns the correct data. But with **.where('locationId', arrayContainsAny: ['29L73oSzdQrzLUow3Mg9','bugdWVC6RRtHoemuxNWE'])** alone, it does not give any error, but simply returns empty data set: **sessionsSnapShot.data.documents.length: 0**.

Edited: when locationId is an array itself, then arrayContainsAny: will work. Yet, if locationId is a String field, then **whereIn:** should be used instead.